# A bound for a solution of a PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $u(t,x):\mathbb{R_+}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a very smooth function, which satisfies the equation:
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}+f(x,u)\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=g(x,u),$$
with initial condition in a noncharacteristic curve. And with $f(x,u)$ and $g(x,u)$ are smooth function too (respect to $x$ and $u$).

Is there a way to bound the solution $u$? maybe using operator theory, in order to get something like this:

$$u=\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}+f(*)\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)^{-1}g(x,u),$$

and then bound the right hand side, or maybe with another technique, as for example, using the characteristics equations:
$$\dfrac{du}{dt}=g(x,u),$$
$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=f(x,u),$$
or perhaps something else? I'm pretty lost here, thanks in advance.